# What is the most efficient way, to create this output, from a single SQL table?

Tags: postgresql, pivot

In short: I would like to use this input:

```
+---+---+---+
| x | y | z |
+---+---+---+
| 1 | 1 | a |
| 1 | 2 | b |
| 1 | 3 | c |
| 2 | 1 | d |
| 2 | 2 | e |
| 2 | 3 | f |
| 3 | 1 | g |
| 3 | 2 | h |
| 3 | 2 | i |
| . | . | . |
| n | . | .
+---+---+---+
```

to generate this output:

```
+---+---------+---------+---------+---------+
| y | z (x=1) | z (x=2) | z (x=3) | z (x=n) |
+---+---------+---------+---------+---------+
| 1 | a       | d       | g       |    .    |
| 2 | b       | e       | h       |    .    |
| 3 | c       | f       | i       |    .    |
+---+---------+---------+---------+---------+
```

Table sample:

```sql
CREATE TABLE "public"."data" (
    "x" text NOT NULL,
    "y" text NOT NULL,
    "z" text NOT NULL,
);
```

- The goal is to generate the output, in the most efficient way possible.
- max(x) will increase over time (->n)
- max(y) should remain constant but may increase by ~10%
- dynamic creation of z(x) columns & names

So far I have the following:

```sql
select * from crosstab('select y, x, z from data order by 1,2')
as ct (y varchar, x1z varchar, x2z varchar, x3z varchar, 
                  x4z varchar, x5z varchar, x6z varchar)
;
```

which seems to work well (so far):

```
+----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+
| y  | x1z | x2z | x3z | x4z | x5z | x6z |
+----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+
| 10 | fo  | ob  | ar  | fo  | ob  | ar  |
| 20 | ob  | ar  | fo  | ob  | ar  | fo  |
| 30 | ar  | fo  | ob  | ar  | fo  | ob  |
+----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+
```

In the previous SQL snippet, I manually defined the static column names.

These should be based on x values & hence 'dynamic' matching below

```sql
select array (select distinct x from data order by x)
```

```
| x_campaigns               |
| ------------------------- |
| ["1","2","3","4","5","6"] |
```

---

Another example to add clarity

- using the same crosstab SQL snippet, with arbitrarily defined column names
- these column names should be dynamically defined, in this example you can say: 'worldcup'+'year'
- in the previous case only 'x' is required, as is

```sql
CREATE TABLE world_cup(
    year varchar(5), 
    game varchar(5), 
    score varchar(5))
    ;

-- insert values ...

select * from crosstab('select game, year, score from world_cup order by 1,2')
as ct (game varchar, WorldCup17 varchar, WorldCup18 varchar,
  WorldCup19 varchar, WorldCup20 varchar, WorldCup21 varchar, WorldCup22 varchar)
```

```
+-------+------------+------------+------------+------------+------------+------------+
| match | worldcup17 | worldcup18 | worldcup19 | worldcup20 | worldcup21 | worldcup22 |
+-------+------------+------------+------------+------------+------------+------------+
| DE_FR |     2-2    |     1-1    |     0-0    |     3-2    |     0-2    |     1-2    |
| EN_DE |     2-0    |     0-2    |     2-1    |     0-0    |     3-0    |     0-0    |
| ES_FR |     0-1    |     0-0    |     1-5    |     0-5    |     1-1    |     3-1    |
+-------+------------+------------+------------+------------+------------+------------+
```

Thoughts?

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/-zHbXWwP)

Version: PostgreSQL 13.6 on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (GCC) 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-44), 64-bit

Comment: "*these should based on x values & hence dynamic*" - not possible. One fundamental restriction of the SQL language is, that the number, names and data types of a query must be known to the database engine while the query is parsed/analyzed. The columns can't be "defined" while the data that is retrieved. SQL wasn't designed for this. Crosstab reports are much better done in the application _displaying_ those results.

Comment: This is PIVOT (in PostgreSQL terms - crosstab). If your values list and, hence, output structure is dynamic then you'd use dynamic SQL, build and execute proper CROSSTAB query.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name, only the column names, the structure remains constant e.g. next set is 100-103

Comment: @Akina, an example?

Comment: If the column names change then this by definition changes the structure of the query.

Comment: Ok, the values in x are unique, these should be used as the pivot column names, which can be defined as required… as shown in the snippet

Comment: The column ‘x1z’ shows the value z, of x=1, for y

Comment: Description and examples can be found: CROSSTAB - https://www.postgresql.org/docs/15/tablefunc.html, dynamic SQL text building needs in common string functions https://www.postgresql.org/docs/15/functions-string.html and STGRING_AGG https://www.postgresql.org/docs/15/functions-aggregate.html

Comment: @Akina, thanks! I did spend a few days "looking for what to search for". In other programming languages, there are alight differences in the naming of variables/ functions etc. In SQL it varies within the language & server type!

Comment: Please define `max(x)` and and `max(y)` *precisely*. Is flipping `x` and `y` an option? Does it have to be dedicated columns, or is an array / document type as result acceptable, too? And always declare your version of Postgres.

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter, version now at added at the end of the post (should it be at the beginning? for future reference). x cannot be exactly defined, as it is a the number of reports, which increases on a daily/weekly etc basis, y are the results & z, extended result information. The output should look as stated but any format is fine. This would be the end output & not used in other SQL operations. I am asking this question, as I have full control over everything! I set up the database last week, so now is the time to change the table!. Noting the input table is already a view on 3 other tables

Comment: Maybe it is time to move on & focus on the frontend implementation as @a_horse_with_no_name, mentioned "Crosstab reports are much better done in the application, displaying, those results"

Comment: One alternative might be to aggregate into a JSON value. Most frontends can easily display that: https://dbfiddle.uk/wNYm_NTW

Comment: Another option might be to create a view using dynamic SQL, e.g. through a trigger. https://dbfiddle.uk/7RokdndB

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name, oooh new toys to play with. Thanks!
They should have been answers or? I'd vote them, if I can...maybe I'm not allowed to yet...

Comment: Well, neither of those do  what you ask for

Comment: OK, but they are alternatives that aid investigation. As you say, the final part is likely better for the frontend. Which is fine by me, as I have to make that next. I ultimately wanted to do everything on the database side, that is possible

Comment: About "dynamic" crosstab: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15514334/939860

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned, it's impossible to create a query that returns a different number of columns each time you run it. In general I recommend to do this kind of pivot/crosstab in the frontend (UI)

Possible alternatives are to aggregate into a JSON value:

```
select y, 
       jsonb_object_agg(concat('x',x, 'z'), y) as xz
from data
group by y
order by y;
```

This returns something like this:

```
y  | xz                                                                            
---+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
10 | {"x1z": "10", "x2z": "10", "x3z": "10", "x4z": "10", "x5z": "10", "x6z": "10"}
20 | {"x1z": "20", "x2z": "20", "x3z": "20", "x4z": "20", "x5z": "20", "x6z": "20"}
30 | {"x1z": "30", "x2z": "30", "x3z": "30", "x4z": "30", "x5z": "30", "x6z": "30"}
```

[JSON example](https://dbfiddle.uk/wNYm_NTW)

---

Another alternative is to write a procedure that dynamically creates a view that does the pivot/crosstab. I am not a fan of the `crosstab()` function and prefer filtered aggregation:

```
select y, 
      max(z) filter (where x = '1') as x1z,
      max(z) filter (where x = '2') as x2z,
      max(z) filter (where x = '3') as x3z,
      max(z) filter (where x = '4') as x4z,
      max(z) filter (where x = '5') as x5z,
      max(z) filter (where x = '6') as x6z
from data
group by y
order by y;
```

This statement follows a pattern that can be automated to dynamically create a view based on the filtered aggregation.

```
create or replace procedure create_crosstab_view()
as
$$
declare
  l_sql text;
begin
  select 'create view crosstab_view as select y, '||
         string_agg(format('max(z) filter (where x = %L) as %I', x, concat('x',x,'z')), ',' order by x)||' from data group by y'
     into l_sql
  from (
    select distinct x from data
  ) t;
  execute 'drop view if exists crosstab_view cascade;';
  execute l_sql;
end;
$$
language plpgsql;
```

After creating the view, you run

```
select *
from crosstab_view;
```

If the source data changes, you re-create the view by running the procedure. You *could* put that into a trigger if you want to.

[Dynamic view example](https://dbfiddle.uk/7RokdndB)

Comment: +1
I cannot up vote, I am too n00b & don't have enough points yet...

Comment: ah but I can accept...game on